# How to hide api url in react native android app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, api, express

I have a nodejs, express and mongodb api that is hosted on heroku.
I want to use that api URL in my react native Android app.
But the problem is if I use that api url in my app then user can it see it easily and use it somewhere that I don't want.
I already secure my post route but I want to know how to hide link inside the app?
And I don't need auth in my app to authenticate the users. User can use the App without any authentication.
Thank You

Answer (score -1):

You are just overthinking about it. Almost every other application makes api request for some data and that cant happen without api endpoints. As per your question i dont think someone can retrieve the code from the decompiled apk that was made through react native. React Native transpile the code into the native language depending upon which OS you want to make a build of either its android or ios.

Comment: Is there any chances for the user to see the api url in my app? If yes then how to a hide that if I'm not hiding then I'll charged more for the services I'm using in my app for unnecessary calls